# Object gets pushed down when text on the right grows

Tags: html, css

How can I put the name David Laecke under the stop image with CSS?

Right now the text David Laecke depends on how much the text on the right grows so that name gets pushed down when the text on the right grows, but I would like it to be independent of the text on the right.

I already made it a `div`, I then changed it to a `span` and I changed the `width` to be less but I can see that it's for some reason taking all the space to the other side of the element, so that's why is being pushed down.

How can I do it? any help would be appreciated.

My HTML code:

```
<h4>
    <form method='post' id='deleteinsight-2' action="insights.php?chapter=1" data-ajax='false'> <input type='hidden' name='deleteinsightinput' value='2'>
        <a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' onclick='deleteinsight(this,event);' style='position:absolute;top:-20px;right: -10px' >Delete</a>
    </form>
    <div class='ui-grid-a'>
      <div class='ui-block-a textfloatleft' > 1 new </div>
      <div class='ui-block-b textfloatright'>   Jan 27 2016, 12:25 pm </div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui-grid-b' style='width:900px;'>
      <div class='ui-block-a' id='blocka'>
        <img  id='imguser' src='http://www.testingcolorvision.com/widget/core/restart.png'>
      </div>
    <div class='ui-block-b' id='blockb'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecen</div>
      <div class='ui-block-c' id='blockc'>
        <button id='btn01' href='#'  data-icon='check' data-iconpos='right' style='width:100px;' onclick='showtextarea(this,2)' >Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span id='namefirstlast'>David  Laecke </span>
</h4>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkt27wvk/

Comment: Put the text in the same div as the image. <div class='ui-block-a' id='blocka'><img  id='imguser' src='http://www.testingcolorvision.com/widget/core/restart.png'><p id='namefirstlast'>David  Laecke </p></div>

Comment: Is there any CSS with this? Also you shouldn't put all these in a `h4` tag

Comment: You're closing the div and starting another element outside of it.. @xpy Whats wrong with using all in `h4`? Maybe the OP is a very excited person! :)

Comment: @Pogrindis as [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), permitted content in an `h4` is only `phrasing-content`, and `form` is not `phrasing-content`.

Comment: @xpy actually `flow content` is permitted, of which `form` would be a member.. But I agree, it's bad syntax.

Comment: @Pogrindis but it says "Permitted content  Phrasing content.". Where did you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the name in the same `<div>` as the image and it should work

Like so:

```
<div class='ui-block-a' id='blocks'>
 <img  id='imguser' src='http://www.testingcolorvision.com/widget/core/restart.png'>
 <br />
 <span id='namefirstlast'>David  Laecke </span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkt27wvk/2/